# Executable may have wrong permissions error while running selenium in cPanel Linux based Terminal

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cpanel

I was trying to execute selenium in cPanel Terminal with Python Language and I run the following codes in the terminal and I got the error "executable may have wrong permissions". What to do please help me. I really need help to upgrade my web app.

```
(AdIS:3.6)[globallo@r041 AdIS]$ python
Python 3.6.8 (default, Dec 26 2018, 08:10:13)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.system('ls') #Directories and Files
__pycache__  adsc  chromedriver  chromedriver_linux64.zip  db.sqlite3  mainApp  manage.py  pages  passenger_wsgi.py  public  stderr.log  test  tmp


>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> d=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedrive')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/globallo/virtualenv/apps.webmatrices.com/AdIS/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE).......
..... selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedrive' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```